# working with neo4j

Tags: neo4j, nosql

Well i am working in gephi and there i have a plugin through which i have exported my graph to neo4j. Once exported it comes out to be folders in which there are some 10-12 files.

Now i have installed neo4j database in my system an running the server in

```
localhost:7474
```

It is displaying neo4j console .

Now my question is how to analyse my neo 4j folder which i have exported from gephi with the help of neo4j console Is this possible

Well i am probably new to this whole concept

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your neo4j folder, you most certainly have a conf directory, with the file "neo4j-server.properties".

At the top you simply pu the path to your database :

```
# location of the database directory
org.neo4j.server.database.location=path/to/data.db
```

where data.db is a neo4j database directory.

Comment: hey Thanks Bendaizer,I did what you told but can you tell me where my graph would be reflected in the server                            Thanks

Comment: By reflected do you mean how you can visualize it ? If so, you can't see the whole database like in gephi. But check first that when you open the web interface, you see the correct number of nodes and relationships. Then you can query it with cypher : "start n=node(*) return n" to get all the nodes for instance. If you just want a visualization tool, you can also use neoclipse (you can found it here : http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize)